# Steam problem, closes automatic?

Tags: steam

I installed Steam, I can start it, but after a few seconds it closes without any errors. What can I do to fix?

When starting with a terminal:

```
mark@Team-Korkel:~$ steam
rm: kan ‘/home/mark/.steam/steam’ niet verwijderen: Is een map
rm: kan ‘/home/mark/.steam/bin’ niet verwijderen: Is een map
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2014-05-27 15:27:50] Startup - updater built May 20 2014 18:30:56
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
[2014-05-27 15:27:50] Checking for update on startup
[2014-05-27 15:27:50] Checking for available updates...
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
[2014-05-27 15:27:51] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1400690891, installed version 1400690891
[2014-05-27 15:27:51] Nothing to do
[2014-05-27 15:27:51] Verifying installation...
[2014-05-27 15:27:51] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2014-05-27 15:27:51] Verification complete
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number
[0527/152752:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
[HTTP Remote Control] HTTP server listening on port 41912.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Generating new string page texture 2: 48x256, total string texture memory is 49,15 KB
Generating new string page texture 3: 256x256, total string texture memory is 311,30 KB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
local (potentially out of sync) copy of roaming config loaded - 226 bytes.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Adding licenses for the following package(s): 0
roaming config store loaded successfully - 226 bytes.
migrating temporary roaming config store
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
ExecCommandLine: "/home/mark/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam"
System startup time: 15,86 seconds
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/mark/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Generating new string page texture 70: 128x256, total string texture memory is 442,37 KB
Generating new string page texture 71: 128x256, total string texture memory is 131,07 KB
Generating new string page texture 72: 64x256, total string texture memory is 507,90 KB
Generating new string page texture 73: 32x256, total string texture memory is 540,67 KB
ExecCommandLine: "/home/mark/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1400690891_client)
Generating new string page texture 80: 8x256, total string texture memory is 548,86 KB
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0527/152809:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1930)] Destroying invalid entry.
```

Using 14.04 64 bit system.

Comment: How did you install, what version Ubuntu. is it 32 or 64 bit? Run `steam` from terminal and past the output into a edit in your question

Comment: Editted the post. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I started Steam in a Terminal, after I closed that Steam is working normal!

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, there were two versions in the software center,
one where I could just click install gave me the same error like you have,
however, the one where I had to click "buy" and then install worked normally.

Try this workaround, even though I had to click "buy", I didn't pay anything
or provide credit card info, or anything like that.